# How to fix wavelet scale in R?

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet

I have been working with temperature data collected at three hours interval. I used biwavelet package in R for wavelet transformation. While analyzing wavelet (wt function) of a time series I changed the argument to dt = 1/8 for daily scaling. But during analyzing wavelet coherency (wtc function) of two time series there was no argument dt. Now I am confused whether my wavelet is considering each rows as daily values. If so, then how do I solve the issue and make the scale correct? Attached graph is produced of wavelet coherency.

```
    t1 <- cbind(1:5000,df$Temp1)
    t2 <- cbind(1:5000,df$Temp2)
    sum(is.na(t1))
    sum(is.na(t2))
    
    wtc_AB <- wtc(t1,t2,s0=8)
    
    
    par(oma=c(0,0,0,1), mar=c(5,4,2,5)+0.1)
    
    plot(wtc_AB,plot.phase = F,xaxt = 'n',
         lty.coi = 2,col.coi = 'grey',
         plot.sig = T,lwd.sig = 0.1,
         ylab = "Scale",xlab = "Years",
         plot.cb = T)
```

[image: wavelet coherency graph]